# DynamoDB fetch query

Tags: java, amazon-dynamodb

```
@DynamoDBTable(tableName = "OrderDashboardMetadata")
public class OrderDashBoardMetaData {

private int position;
private Date ETA = null;
private List<String> notes;

@DynamoDBHashKey(attributeName = "queueName")
private String queueName;

@DynamoDBRangeKey(attributeName = "orderId")
private String orderId;

@DynamoDBIndexHashKey(globalSecondaryIndexName = "city")
private String city;

@DynamoDBIndexRangeKey(globalSecondaryIndexName = "city")
private String fcId;

@DynamoDBIndexHashKey(globalSecondaryIndexName = "orderState")
private String orderState;

@DynamoDBAttribute(attributeName = "action")
private String action;

@DynamoDBAttribute(attributeName = "createdTime")
private Date createdTime = new Date();

@DynamoDBAttribute(attributeName = "updatedTime")
private Date updatedTime = new Date();
```

Hi

I have a table structure like the one above.
What would be query to fetch results only that have

1) queueName -- > PFS
2) ETA --> greater than 1st jan 2017
3)order state --  PO

Kindly suggest full query for the above scenario in **JAVA**.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you have not annotated so assuming ETA is also an DDBAttribute

```
 Map<String, AttributeValue> expValues = new HashMap<>();
 expValues.put(":hv", new AttributeValue("PFS"));
 expValues.put(":osv", new AttributeValue("PO"));
 expValues.put(":etav", new AttributeValue("2017-01-01"));

 QueryRequest q = new QueryRequest("OrderDashboardMetadata");
 q.setKeyConditionExpression("queueName = :hv");
 q.setFilterExpression("orderState = :osv and ETA > :etav");
 q.setExpressionAttributeValues(expValues);
 QueryResult r = dbClient.query(q);
```

Note: Dates are stored as S (string type). The Date values are stored as ISO-8601 formatted strings.

Comment: upvote and accept is nice way to say thanks, will help others as well.